# What is the best way to hide elements with a certain ID that doesn't effect the performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I want to create one html page with multiple 'pages' inside.

I want to have a few pages that show different visualizations (D3 layouts). And with there being lots of data passed to these views I can't just simply 'hide' the ones I don't want to view.

Originally, I would just give the different views their own class, for example, view1, view2 and so on. Then have tabs at the top to chose what view I want. So if I click on VIEW1, it sets everything with the class 'view1' to visible, and everything else, hidden. But this way they are still there effecting the page as they are still there, just invisible.

What is the best way to have multiple pages in one html page ?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Can you post the code for the same? Also have you considered `hide(),show()` on the tabs instead of on all the underlying elements?

Comment: how about css `display` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with jQueryUI. Here is a [link](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)

You will have your views with your content and when you click on the tab the view will load:

```
<li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
```

Comment: that looks perfect. Ill give it a go and get back to you

Comment: I dont think i did :( i think I just stuck to setting display to none which done the trick, but your way seems like it should work